# Appending trained SVM data to a pickle file

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, svm

Can I append newly trained SVM data to existing old SVM trained file?

note: I don't want to replace I just want to append.

```
# Read old classifier data
classifier = None
filename = 'svm_classifier.pkl'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    classifier = pickle.load(file)

# Write new classifier data
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(classifier, file)
```

I have tried this, but it deletes all file content.

Comment: I don't think so. As soon as you train the SVM on new data, it will lose its old weights.